# .htaccess rule help in a plex non-windows hosting environment

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having trouble writing a rule for .htaccess which will redirect HTML to PHP. I'm using 302 until I get it to work right - then I'll change to a 301. I found several postings that describe this, but I am having problems - possibly because I'm running a hosting package, and each client is in a virtual/subfolder (sorry for poor description of hosting environment).

The rule I am using is
...

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [R=302]

...

When I try to go to https://dmcelebratealife.com/index.html I get a 404 message saying:

https://www.dmcelebratealife.com/var/www/vhosts/dmcelebratealife.com/public_html/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I added the following and it seemed to work for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php [R=302]
```

Comment: Thats because you are exposing the extension to the world.  Which is not a good idea.  I was hiding it.

Comment: Can you tell me why it's not a good idea?  I'm not familiar with why the extensions should be hidden.  I thought that if the original website used HTML and I switched to PHP that the 301 was needed for search engines.  Always glad to learn a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and is domain-independent.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(?!.+\.\w{2,4})(.+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(?!.+\.\w{2,4})(.+)$ $1.html [L]
```

The first two redirect to the **php** file if it exists.  If it doesn't then the second two will try for an **HTML** file.

Note it doesn`t use a **302** as you don't want to tell the user what you are doing.  This does an internal redirect.

This means that if the user types in

`https://www.example.com/test`

it will remain in the URL box, but the following file will be executed

`https://www.example.com/test.php`

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm going to study this (to understand it) and test it.   I plan to use a 301 as I want the search engines to switch from xxxx.html to xxxx.php without losing current SEO standings.

Comment: The code didn't do what I wanted - but it helped me do a little more testing on my own and I came up with something that works for me.  I am posting it as a stand-alone comment below.

Comment: They expose the structure of your design to would-be hackers.  And its more for your users to type in.  For my website, the user just types in **example.com**.  Why even make the user type in **https** or **www**.